# sql query to affect multiple rows dynamically

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a query that affects multiple rows in my table dynamically.

1)Each row represents a vendor with different pricing for services.

2)Pricing is determined based on how a customer answers a survey.

3)Each answer will flag a price spike or not based on answering the question, "Yes or no".

4)These price spikes are more or less severe depending on the vendor.

5)while logging in as a customer and filling said survey, i want to create a query that compares your information to all vendors that offer the product selected.

could anyone tell me how to go about creating this query? So far i have stored all of the customer's answers in individual sessions.

My vendor database is as follows
vedor name/ base price/ question 1 - price spike if customer answer's no/ question 2 - price spike if customer answer's no/ question 3 - price spike if customer answer's no

if the customer answers question 1 with 'no', vendor 1 will charge $100 more.

if the customer answers question 1 with 'no', vendor 2 will charge $50 more.

if the customer answers question 1 with 'no', vendor 3 will charge $20 more.

if the customer answers question 2 with 'no', vendor 1 will charge $10 more.

if the customer answers question 2 with 'no', vendor 2 will charge $15 more.

if the customer answers question 2 with 'no', vendor 3 will charge $40 more.

I want to display the following after the customer submits the survey in a data grid

Vendor 1 name / Price after considering all price spikes

Vendor 2 name / Price after considering all price spikes

Vendor 3 name / Price after considering all price spikes

Comment: well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use variables to store the numbers. Query your database to get each vendors numbers.

Something like:

```
 string sqlVendor1 = "Select * from VendorTable Where VendorID = 'Whatever'";
 DataSet ds = Conn.CreateDataSet(sql)
 DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]

 string sqlVendor2 = "Select * from VendorTable Where VendorID = 'Whatever'";
 DataSet ds2 = Conn.CreateDataSet(sql)
 DataRow dr2 = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]

 Int32 Vendor1 = Convert.ToInt32((dr["BasePrice"]));
 Int32 Vendor2 = Convert.ToInt32((dr2["BasePrice"]));

 if (cbQuestion1.Checked)
 {
//Add whatever to the variable as they make the selections.
 Vendor1 = 400;
}
else if (cbQuestion2.Checked)
{
 Vendor2 = 500;
}
```

It will be much deeper, but your information was very vague. Post what code you have if you want a clearer answer.

Comment: If customer selects product X then list all vendors that offer product X and their price.

(note: vendors set a base price. The price I want to list is subject to change based on the survey I discussed above)

((If question 1 = true then Price = Price * A where A is the increase indicated by the vendor

+

If question 2 = true then Price = Price * B where B is the increase indicated by the vendor

+

If question 3 = true then Price = Price * C where C is the increase indicated by the vendor)

Divided by Z where Z is equal to the number of total Questions answered True in the table.)

Comment: The primary function I was looking for was dataset and datarow to target the row of a table. Also, is there a way to standardize your datarow statement? The amount of vendors in the table is not fixed and I want to run the above pseudo code query for every row in the table.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset Check that link out and spend time reading. Data is complex and you need to understand it.

Comment: @michaelhanon I think he is asking: how do you take a row of data from one table (for example: `patient data: patient_id, patient_age, patient_conditions, etc`), and run that row (stored in a session array) against another table's full set of rows (for example `treatment types table`) such that, if `patient_age` range = 40 - 60 and `patient_conditions` = y, give cost discount x for treatment z

Comment: Yes, that is a better explanation of what i am trying to do. the table size is dynamic so, ideally, the function would iterate repeatedly until the function has run across all rows. thank you

Comment: @Growler Haha good job decrypting that. Ill leave that to you as I am not very familiar with that technique.